# Request.Form giving extra values from Dynamic Textboxes

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i am working with dynamic TextBoxes and then Getting their Values in code behind file. I am creating these boxes using Javascript. my asp.net page code is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var counter = 1;

            $("#addButton").click(function () {

                if (counter > 10) {
                    alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
                    return false;
                }

                var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);


                newTextBoxDiv.html('<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
                      '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

                newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
                counter++;
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form id="form2" runat="server">

        <h1>jQuery add / remove textbox example</h1>

        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1" type='text' name="textname" />
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID='TextBoxesGroup'>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="addButton" runat="server">Add TextBox</asp:LinkButton>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</body>
```

i have one Textbox shown on the page, which should shows only one values when no dynamic Textbox is created. My C# code is

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = txt1.Text + ",";
        if (TextBoxesGroup.Controls.Count  > 0)
        {           
            for (int i = 1; i <= TextBoxesGroup.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                name += Request.Form["textbox" + i] + ",";
            }    
        }

        Label1.Text = name;
    }
```

on asp:button click it should display all the values separated by (,). but it is only showing top 2 values, one of which is asp:Textbox and second is dynamic Textbox,, i want the values of all the Textboxes created dynamically, and when no dynamic textbox is added it should only show the value from asp:textBox... Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why not set an `asp:HiddenField` equal to the comma delimited textbox values?

Comment: Nah.. hiddenField wont do the job here.. i think.. but have u tried this code on ur end.. to see what is the Problem??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Html `input` elements created through javascript on the client, are not going to be in `TextBoxesGroup.Controls` on the server.

Changes in the client DOM structure have no effect on the `Page`'s `Control` tree. The only thing affected will be the content of `HttpRequest` during postback. One way to know how many dynamically created `input` elements contributed to `Request.Form` data is to pass this information as part of the request. This is why you will have to go with the hidden field suggestion. The hidden field value will bring back the count of client-side inputs. You have to set it in javascript every time you create a new input, read it in server-side code, convert to integer and use in your `for` loop.

Add

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="txtDynamicCount" value="0" />
```

to the the markup inside `form` tag.
In javascript `click` event after `counter++;` line add

```
$("#txtDynamicCount").val(counter);
```

In `Button1_Click`:

```
int count;
if (!int.TryParse(txtDynamicCount.Value, out count))
    count = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
...
}
```

The important difference from the other answer is that textboxes (input elements) will not persist between form submits.

Comment: They are AppendingTo asp:panel(TextBoxesGroup), i am getting top 2 values from this group.. there is something wrong with this loop of the way i am creating these inputs...As TextBoxesGroup.Controls.Count is not getting exact position in the loop.

Comment: IF not Javascript dynamic Boxes then how do u think i should add this many TextBoxes on button click then Read there values,, Separate them by (,)..

Comment: Yes i do get it now that Client's DOM structure is different to what page Control's Tree is.. can you give me brief on how Hidden Field will do the Job for me... as i dont know on this ...Thanks

Comment: Wow, Just Tried it and it worked like straight away... it does what i want it to.. i have tested it little now and will implement it in my real application, if any problems i will contact again.. Thankyou soo much.. you saved my Day..:)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot populate server controls in client side. Instead, you want to populate them from server. Here is the sample -

[image]

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:LinkButton ID="addButton" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click">Add TextBox</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" /><br/>
Posted Results: <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

private List<int> _controlIds;

private List<int> ControlIds
{
    get
    {
        if (_controlIds == null)
        {
            if (ViewState["ControlIds"] != null)
                _controlIds = (List<int>)ViewState["ControlIds"];
            else
                _controlIds = new List<int>();
        }
        return _controlIds;
    }
    set { ViewState["ControlIds"] = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        foreach (int id in ControlIds)
        {
            var textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.ID = id.ToString();

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textbox);
        }
    }
}

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var reqs = ControlIds;
    int id = ControlIds.Count + 1;

    reqs.Add(id);
    ControlIds = reqs;

    var textbox = new TextBox();
    textbox.ID = id.ToString();

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textbox);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ids = ControlIds;
    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        var textbox = (TextBox)PlaceHolder1.FindControl(id.ToString());
        Label1.Text += textbox.Text + ", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.. it does the Job.. but still it is posting back the page not the Ajax way.. Thanks. Anyway to make this it in add TextBoxes without posting back.. i am still new to .NET :)

Comment: You can use UpdatePanel if you want ajax. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx